# Is there a way to prevent another dog from pooping on our grass?

Tags: dogs, behavior, feces, defecation

Our regularly-trimmed grass outside our gate has been pooped on by another dog. I don't know the dog and I've been trying to determine which dog it was.

I know about dogs being territorial, and that another dog might not poop on our grass once he realizes that our dog is in the house.

Is there any way I can use my dog to mark the grass to notify the other dog that he should not go there? or Is there another way to prevent the other dog from pooping on our grass?

Comment: I would suggest a sign asking owners not to let their dog poop on your lawn. That's just rude and inconsiderate. Or is this patch of grass on the other side of a sidewalk in front of your house? Is that gray area for who/what is allowed to poop there?

Comment: Sometimes it is very difficult to prevent a dog from going when he wants to go.  But when it happens the owner should be considerate enough to at least clean up.

Comment: Depending on where you live, it could be a violation of local laws to not clean up after your dog. I still think pursuing the owner is the best thing you can do here.

Comment: @d2jxp Where I live, there is no such law. But how can I know the owner when I don't even know the dog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some ideas, since you are unable to identify the other dog:

1. use a motion-activated sprinkler

   - This will probably scare the dog and owner for the first few times, signaling that you don't want others entering over your grass and doing things
2. spread a repellant or unpleasant odor

   - ammonia, vinegar, citrus peels or oil, [Liquid Fence](http://www.liquidfence.com/dog-cat-repellents.html). You won't need a great amount, and it might kill plants, so apply it to the edge of the grass.
   - If you do buy a dog repellent, follow the instructions because you don't want to cause any harm, just deter the habit.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, a domesticated dog marking its territory will simply encourage other domesticated dogs to add their own mark.  I'm not sure this applies to feces, however, as urine is the primary means of territory marking.

It is possible that getting your dog to mark your yard will prompt the other dog to mark *instead* of defecating, as most dogs are seemingly indiscriminate about where they'll mark, but quite a few are *very* discriminating about where they'll defecate (as anyone who has ever suffered outside in freezing rain waiting for their dog to find "just the right spot" will attest!).

However, this will probably be more trouble than its worth.  If this isn't an isolated incident, you'll have to have your dog mark the borders of your property regularly for there to be even a chance of it working.

You're better off using other means to try and prevent the other dog from seeing your property as a good location for relieving himself/herself.

The simplest solution is a fence.  Even a small ornamental fence is likely to be a sufficient deterrent:

[image: a small ornamental garden fence]

Alternately, you can plant something other than grass along the borders of your property.  If it the vegetation is sufficiently dense, most dogs will pass it by (then again, we've had a dog trample the one large flower we have in the corner of our yard and deposit a "present" for us right on top of the bent leaves!).

You can also try something based upon a motion sensor, as woliveirajr suggested.  There are motion sensor activated ultrasonic pest control devices that supposedly work on dogs, as a possible alternative to a sprinkler that might make you rather unpopular with your neighbors.

Comment: unpopular with your *wet* neighbors.... :)